# Declare a function that implements an interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this TypeScript code in a manually created .d.ts file:

```
export interface IBeforeHook {
     foo: Function,
     bar: Function
}


export type BeforeHookCallbackMode = (h: IBeforeHook) => void;
export type BeforeHookRegularMode = (h?: IBeforeHook) => Promise<any>;
export type BeforeHookObservableMode = (h?: IBeforeHook) => Observable<any>;
export type BeforeHookSubscriberMode = (h?: IBeforeHook) => Subscriber<any>;
export type BeforeHookEEMode = (h?: IBeforeHook) => EventEmitter;

type TBeforeHookTemp =
  BeforeHookCallbackMode |
  BeforeHookRegularMode |
  BeforeHookObservableMode |
  BeforeHookSubscriberMode |
  BeforeHookEEMode
```

I would like all of the TBeforeHook types to extend/implement the IBeforeHook interface...how can I do that?

I want to do something like:

```
export type TBeforeHook extends TBeforeHookTemp implements IBeforeHook {

}
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
export type TBeforeHook = TBeforeHookTemp & IBeforeHook;
```